# Accused of cheating on masters final; afraid that appeal will bring retaliation (ruining PhD applications)

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, cheating

A friend of mine is finishing up a masters program and has applied to PhD programs around the nation last fall, as well as within the existing college. She had received several glowing letters of recommendation, including one from a professor of a current class (this last fall semester).

This professor has now accused my friend of cheating and collusion on the final examination with another student in the class; which is absolutely not the case. The final exam was a take-home, open-book, open-Internet exam of which one-of-three portions was multiple choice and she and the other student answered a large portion of their incorrect questions similarly--a red flag it seems. It should be said that every prior assignment working together was encouraged so it seems obvious that they would have similar notes and thought processes.

Now, here's where it gets messy: The professor is behaving as the prosecutor, judge, jury and executioner. He told them both that the "data is irrefutable" and he "doesn't want an appeal from either of you - my mind is already made up." He has not followed the procedure for the school's academic integrity guidelines in any way which, most disturbingly, completely removes her ability to an appeal. He has made several academic threats such as going to the doctoral programs they have submitted to "let them know of this incident" if they do not show any "credible remorse." He has decided he will come up with a secondary exam that can do nothing but be combined with and hurt their existing final exam grade.

Obviously, my friend is frustrated, angry, stressed out and frightened at these events, especially during this fragile time of waiting for responses to her applications.

So what can be done? The obvious thing would be to go to his department chairs herself and bring to light this ludicrous behavior and, if found that integrity is in question appeal the decision. But this would bring along **one major issue**: Once done the professor will surely reach out the academic programs to retract their recommendation, which one would assume would look incredibly bad to an admissions committee. She also has an "incomplete" in this class until this is resolved which is assumed to be--or will be--affecting the current school's PhD program application. He truly has her powerless and backed into a corner.

What would you do knowing this decision could *affect your entire future, academic and beyond*? (This is in the US, if that matters)

**Edit for clarification for secondary exam:**
The professor would not give my friend the new exam until he was able to talk to her on the phone. Her initial and current desire is to just get the exam and complete it to get this whole thing over with without affecting her applications; but she has no intention of admitting any guilt. The professor seems quite annoyed that she did not show remorse or admit any wrongdoing when asking for the exam (I was not there, but his email providing the exam said that the conversation "did not go as he anticipated" and did "little to alleviate his concern," I'm assuming because she did not admit to cheating).

As for the secondary exam, he has given her about half of original multiple choice questions from the first exam, some of which she answered correctly and some of which she did not. His stipulation is that any wrong answers will bring down her final exam score further from what she scored initially and any correct answers will not affect the grade positively or negatively. He has withheld her final exam this entire time so she has no idea which questions she actually answered incorrectly, but this also forbids her from verifying any of his claims as well. Further, she will have to complete additional long-form essays again, which he has not come up with yet.

He has also given her the option of not completing the secondary exam and taking a full letter grade off of her final grade (likely, a B-) and has told her he will not give her anything higher than a B+. I assume she has an A- but, again, she doesn't know how she did on the exam. He has said that he "really wants to give them both a B+" for what that is worth.

Comment: _He has not followed and procedure for the school's academic integrity guidelines in any way_ — Escalate to his boss, documentation in hand.  She might also consider pre-emptively withdrawing her PhD applications before the professor can poison them, and then reapplying next year with a different set of letters.

Comment: @JeffE Sound advice. Do you not think silently taking the secondary exam  without any admission of guilt from herself, possibly taking a lower grade just to finish the class, remove the incomplete and hear back from the applied programs and then, afterwards, going to his boss is a viable option? I know that waiting a year just to re-apply would devastate her (plus she's sunk hundreds of dollars into applications alone).

Comment: @JDoe If she goes along with the professor's program he will be able to present it as a silent admission of guilt.

Comment: Guilt and punishment is generally a matter for the university in conjunction with the prof.  Contacting outside universities on an unadjudicated issue would not be a wise move for the prof.  Your friend should go to the dean, and tell of the threats.  Even if found guilty of cheating, it's unlikely that the prof would be allowed to poison applications

Comment: FWIW this was also [posted on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskAcademia/comments/40l9vv/accused_of_cheating_by_prof_with_recommendation/)

Comment: You can't tell someone not to appeal; it's always their choice. That's kind of the point. By saying outright "I don't want an appeal", this professor is basically saying "you may well see my behaviour as unfair and/or unprofessional, but I want you to just accept it". It could be argued that's tantamount to an admission that they have grounds for grievance. At the least, it's an instruction to disregard the university's misconduct and ethics procedures, which is itself unprofessional, unethical, and unenforceable. **Get everything in writing, and raise a grievance with the university.**

Comment: _Do you not think silently taking the secondary exam . . . and then, afterwards, going to his boss is a viable option?_ — No, I don't. Go to the chair/dean/grievance committee *now*. Deal with the cheating accusation *now*. The longer she waits, the more muddled the truth gets.

Comment: Could you elaborate further on this second exam situation?  It seems to me if the teacher is giving an out that doesn't involve going through the extended bureaucracy then I would take that.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Yes. I've added an edit with clarification on the secondary exam.

Comment: I was falsely accused of plagiarism/cheating by an undergrad English prof who claimed that I could not have the resources checked out from the library since they had been checked out for "longer than undergrads are allowed to check out books". I went to talk to her in her office to no avail. I took the entire stack of books and went into the Dean's office and refused to leave until I was heard. She was forced to admit that she was wrong, to apologize and to fix my grade.

Comment: I sincerely hope that this is not a prof on any subject where one needs to come to logical conclusions based on evidence. To state that mere correlation of answers on a multiple choice test constitutes irrefutable proof of collusion is quite moronic.

Comment: It is **your right** for the grade and misconduct accusations to be appealed. An instructor **cannot** usurp the university's academic integrity policies. Bring it up to your university's student affairs office (or equivalent) immediately.

Comment: Also, the professor's demand for remorse is a sign of arrogance and unwillingness to accept the possibility that the students may not have cheated. I would not be surprised if it turns out there existed a personal reason for these accusations unrelated to this incident.

Comment: To make it clear, you already know something is morally very wrong when the professor already decides the grades in advance of the second exam, because then the second exam is pointless, and only wastes your friend's time. Also, people who are afraid of doing things in the open are almost always up to no good, so the fact that the professor does not want to bring it up to the administration is a clear sign of malice. If your friends did not cheat, she SHOULD NEVER take an offer of a SO-CALLED way out, because she would be absolving the professor from CHEATING HER.

Comment: "The final exam was a take-home, open-book, open-Internet exam." What??? On what basis can you even accuse anyone of cheating on such a thing.  Such an exam is basically an exercise in cheating, *by design.* The grade should go to Google.

Answer (score 96):

A student who is falsely accused of cheating should follow the official appeal or grievance process, even if they are threatened with retaliation for doing so.  To threaten to retaliate if an appeal is made would be blatant misconduct.  The student should keep careful records of everything that has happened thus far.

Unfortunately the student has no control over what the professor may communicate to institutions the student sent applications to.  I think the student should prepare to wait for admissions results, possibly until the next application cycle, when recommendations from other faculty could be used.

Comment: Exactly. A professor might say they don't want an appeal, but that's not really their call. Although I'm most confused about a multiple choice test in grad school — who does that?

Comment: @anonymous-physicist, Thanks for the answer! I'm curious, when you say "wait, possibly until the next application cycle" do you mean wait to act on the accusations or retract her applications and wait to re-apply with different recommendations (like JeffE mentions in comments above).

Comment: Revised.  Act on accusations now (or according to the timeline given in the policy), but wait and see on the graduate school applications - those may take care of themselves.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I propose to change the beginning of your answer to "A student who believes s/he is falsely accused ..." - it seems the issue is not yet settled with a conclusion.

Comment: @YuxinZhou one must assume background information in the question is true to answer it.  See the beginning of paragraph three.

Comment: @YuxinZhou The student certainly knows whether or not they cheated, and therefore whether or not they were falsely accused.

Comment: Similarity of answers is a strong indication, though not proof of cheating. It is grounds for closer investigation, but, per se, does not constitute sufficient evidence to make a full case. Your friend should insist on a formal investigation - but only if she is *really sure* that there was no academic misconduct, or else it may backfire really badly. I remember a case of a student who made a strong point about not having cheated which could be proven wrong. Grave mistake. If she was honest and the prof is not in possession of further evidence hidden from you, then an appeal may be in place.

Comment: "To threaten to retaliate if an appeal is made would be blatant misconduct." Exactly this.  Not in academia, but as an NCO in the Army, I would occasionally have subordinates that questioned my handling of their misconduct and threatened to go up the chain of command.  My response was never anything but "go right ahead". If you are doing the right thing, an appeal to higher authority should never bother you in the least.

Comment: @Kevin: even if you have *not* been doing the right thing, threatening retaliation against any appeal is a pretty awful tactic; it’s more likely to dig you further into trouble than to succeed in covering it up, in an even halfway-honest institutional culture.

Comment: This takes a very idealized view of the bureaucracy of administration who will decide her fate.  It also seems to ignore that she would also probably open herself up to a much more severe penalty than just taking the test again and accepting a lower grade.  The administrators may agree with the professor that the answers in common couldn't be coincidence.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor: If the university administration does not deal justly, then the solution is very simple. Tell the whole world the name of the university and the professor. Eventually the real truth will come to light. Yes, there will be repercussions, but **is it worth going into academia if no one there fights for the truth any longer**? If there are, then why should we be afraid to make the whole incident public? Better to make others beware this university and professor than to let the darkness prevail.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor: that will vary by school. At my school, an appeal can never increase the penalty for cheating. The appeal board may decide in favor of the professor (upholding the penalty) or the student (removing or reducing it), but they cannot second-guess the professor by increasing the penalty.

Comment: @user21820 you're being very idealistic though.  I don't want to get too controversial by naming names but one person's whistle blower is another person's treasonous criminal.  In this case the only evidence is that a lot of questions have the same wrong answer.  By escalating the situation OP's friend is essentially putting themselves at the mercy of the professor's colleague's who will likely make the same interpretation.

Comment: @OswaldVeblen wouldn't that be murky since she hasn't been officially accused under university guidelines yet?  In other words what if university guidelines say "if you're cheating then you automatically fail the course in which you were cheating".  Once OP insists on taking the accusation down the official trail it seems she would be subject to the minimum as set out by the guidelines and that the prof's suggested punishment couldn't substitute for the university guidelines.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor: I said "If the university administration does not deal justly". If no one in the university wants to stand up against wrongful accusation, then the best action to take is to expose it. It is precisely because people who know the truth are afraid of losing their social status that a lot of evil remains hidden. Are you even aware of things like http://www.theguardian.com/world/2015/dec/17/the-mystery-of-indias-deadly-exam-scam?

Comment: @user21820 Call me a coward, but dying for an exam doesn't seem a good result

Comment: @DanielF: When life is at stake, I say with no hesitation: Preserve life as far as possible. But it may be possible to preserve life and expose the evil, from somewhere safer. On the other hand, if preserving our own life is likely to lead to destruction of others' lives, then we have to think about whether we want to take the plunge instead.

Answer (score 20):

Let me tell you a story.

Once I was driving in my car when out of the blue the traffic police pulled me over. A single police officer was present and informed me that I drove over a red light. I denied any such thing and honestly had no recollection of ignoring a red light. I also had a passenger who did not see any red light violations. The officer insisted and handed me a fine.

I decided to go to court and proclaim my innocence. The fine amount was not a big problem for me at the time but being accused of something I did not do was always a big problem for me and still is.

So I went to court.

I was a student at the time, intimidated by the court, intimidated by the process, intimidated by those with the power namely the judge and the prosecutor.

The prosecutor got the officer on the stand first and asked his side of the story. The officer related a tale of complete fiction, well a completely different story to how I remembered the incident. Apparently the road was wet and conditions were tricky.

The prosecutor finally asks, "When the light turned red, was it safe for the accused to stop?"
The officer answers, "No."

And this is where I made my first mistake.

Suddenly I was thinking why am I even here? Why did he fine me if it was unsafe to stop? What is going on? Didn't he just prove my case? While I am grappling with this the judge asks me whether I have any questions for the officer and still almost dazed I answered no.

Then I made my second mistake.

The judge asks, "So you agree with everything the officer said?"
And still completely off balance by the turn of events I said, "Yes".

And the trap snaps shut.

The judge then says, "As you are not an attorney I will assist you with some questions, Officer, was it still safe to stop when the light turned orange?"
The officer responded, "Yes"

And then everything made sense. They set the trap, they got me hook, line and sinker and the rest of the proceedings were just them reeling me in.

Note: this was in South Africa and in the traffic courts this would not have been a full blown judge.

I was pretty angry and surely it is a miscarriage of justice perpetrated by the people in power who should be acting fairly and in the spirit of the law. I was also disappointed in myself for taking their bait and not just sticking to the truth of what I recalled about the incident.

---

How does this story relate? Be wary when someone offers you an easy way out of a sticky situation.

In my calmer, less arrogant and righteous old age, instead of aggressively attacking the professor let me consider his position in a kindly light.

As a professor I receive two papers with enough similarities that it convinces me that there was cheating. I feel angry, betrayed, disappointed. I have two courses of action, either I follow the official disciplinary steps or I rap them over the knuckles and hope they learn their lessons. (I assume the consequences of being found guilty of cheating through the official disciplinary channel will be a lot more severe than what they have been asked to do)

What will convince me of the innocence of one of the students?

---

My advice is to stay calm. You have to live with the decision you make. I would definitely advise against admitting guilt when innocent. Is there any student bodies that could offer support? Is there any counselors at the university the dispute can be discussed with in confidence? Has the student point of view been clearly communicated with the professor?

The biggest problem here is the professor withholding the proof which prevents a defense by the students. My course of action would be to try and convince the professor to go through the papers with me so I can explain why I chose the answers that I did and to see first hand why the professor believes the proof is irrefutable. A heart felt email/letter (without any threats or accusations) could help to facilitate this.

Answer (score 9):

## Probability of two persons getting the exact same answers in a 40 question with 4 choices QCM are high

Given that the birthday theorem applies, the probability a bunch of 500 chimpanzees having the same answers in a bunch of 500 is about 2% ([Calculus here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=squareroot%282*500*ln%281%2F%281-%281%2F40%5E4%29%29%29%29))

If it is known they have the same amount of right answers we get about 3.5%([here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=squareroot%282*500*ln%281%2F%281-%281%2F%2830%5E4%2B10%5E4%29%29%29%29%29)), far from impossible. Data lies. It can multiply since people tend to make the same choises given the same formation and environement.

Your friend should follow the appeal procedure right now because the professor is either not liking her or not knowing any statistics to estimate the probability and thinks falsely. Yes, naive probabilities will give him a 0.0000004% of probability but it is an error.

Not an exact answer but hope it can help.

Comment: And that math even presumes that the answers are equally likely.  Many MC tests tend to have the right answer, a close-to-right-but-not answer, a wrong answer, and a do-you-seriously-think-this-is-right?-were-you-even-in-my-class? answer.  Since the close-to-right-but-not answer is more likely to be chosen, that weighs even more heavily in favor of a handful of wrong answers being the same.

Comment: The first probability assumes random distribution.

Comment: The linked math is wrong. You've written 40^4 (i.e. 4 questions with 40 choices each) rather than 4^40 (i.e. 40 questions with 4 choices each) and I'm not sure what you've got there is even the right formula. Not even a million chimpanzees have a decent chance of two of them having the exact same answers. However, if you are willing to accept a significantly higher chance of two people having the same answers then the probability can become quite high.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden you know, the probability in a class of 23 person there at least two with the same birthday is about 50% if I remember well. And for the inversion, I will correct

Comment: @LudovicZenohateLagouardette I'm familiar with the birthday paradox. It's still incorrect. There are 4^40 possible ways to answer, therefore every chimp has at most a 500/4^40 chance of getting the exact same set of answers as any other. For 500 chimps, the probability of at least two getting the same set of answers by chance is thus at most 1 - (1 - 500/4^40)^500, which is around 2 in 10^19. 4^40 is simply too large compared to the 365 days that appear in the birthday paradox, you need significantly more monkeys to make this work. You're using the wrong formula.

Answer (score 3):

Your friend is in an extremely precarious position and falling back to the just approach may not actually yield the best outcome.  In other words the immediate reaction that she should indeed appeal may not be the best course of action, at least not without preparation.

If your friend has access to the questions that she got wrong, she should go back and find the websites/resources that led her to think the answer she chose was the right one and document it.  I think in most people's experience with multiple choice tests, the answers can almost always be narrowed down to two even when there are 4 possibles.  If possible, perhaps document just how wrong the other possibilities were.  She should present that to the professor and see what he says.  I assume this exchange will be via email.  If he is unswayed, which I expect, then she should meet him in person.  In that meeting your friend should prepare to stand her ground that she didn't cheat and leverage whatever relationship and trust she has gained up until this point to get him to waver in his resolve.

If this fails then I would seriously consider taking the second final as the way I understand the situation, her existing grade will still count but this will perhaps be averaged in but only if it is a worse grade?

I don't know the official university guidelines but chances are the repercussions of taking the official path could be much worse.  Consider that cheating on a test isn't murder where the people making the guilt/non-guilty decision are going to be looking for extra evidence.  They're going to see the same thing that the professor sees which is that they got the same set of wrong answers.  The people your friend would appeal to are the professor's colleagues not a group of peers.  Keeping in mind that even if she does win this appeal, there would be nothing to stop the professor to take back his recommendations.  If she does decide to make an official appeal then one approach she could consider would be asking the schools to which she has already used his recommendation to withdraw it because of an ongoing university issue.  By her asking this, it is less likely they'll suspect the problem is cheating and more likely to assume the problem is a complaint against him.  As long as she doesn't actually imply anything untrue then this should be perfectly fine.  If, subsequent to her asking for those recommendations to be withdrawn, he comes around to withdraw them, it will look better for your friend than if she hadn't already withdrawn them.

Comment: Thanks for evaluating the "most just" route separately from the "most advantageous." I added some more details about the exam to the question. To note: _Under no circumstances should she tell him that she made this recording._ Unfortunately, this is illegal in this state. All parties to a phone call or conversation must be aware of it's recording in MA.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins I took the recording part out.  It was never a pivotal part of the "strategy" so the main message doesn't really change.  Also the advice of going to a lawyer was predicated on the assumption that they made a recording that is of questionable legality that they wanted to use so that came out too.

Answer (score 2):

She should follow the designated appeals procedure.  She should file a complaint with the University concerning the professor's behavior in this matter.  She should have an attorney competent in this area of law write the university expressing concerns that the professor might attempt to interfere with her application at her current university or other universities, and pointing out any civil liability the university might face if that were to happen.

In addition, she should think back on her time in the class to any actions that might indicate behavior toward her that was suggestive of any violation of federal law due to any protected category into which she might fall.  One example of this would be any form of sex or race based discrimination.  Any behaviors that she can recall along those lines would of course could be valuable additional information that the attorney could include when the letter is written to the university.  I'm not suggesting making something up, but she should think back on things that might have been ambiguous at the time they happened that now in light of everything that has happened could have appeared to be some form of discrimination.  I realize that the professor wrote a letter of recommendation for her earlier, so showing discrimination could be a tall hurdle, but if any discrimination is being shown toward her it should be brought out in the open.

No matter which way she handles this, the possibility exists that the professor could cause her some difficulty at her current school.  I feel that making a fairly aggressive response is the way to give her the best possible outcome both at other schools and at her current school as well.

Comment: "I'm not suggesting making something up"

Well, everything else you're saying kind of suggests you do. So far we have a case of academic misconduct, no indication whatsoever from OP that this is a case of discrimination, but you suggest spinning it as a discrimination story anyway. I get that's probably "good tactics" legal wise, but it's also pretty despicable.

Comment: Not despicable in any way.  The professor seems to be acting in a way that is disproportionate to the alleged offense, and in violation of university policy.  Perhaps the professor just has a chip on their shoulder, or perhaps something else motivates them.  It is completely fair in light of the current situation that the student recall the professor's behavior for the semester to see if anything else happened that at the time she just dismissed, but looking at it now she might be able to see it as part of a pattern.  To suggest that she not look back for a pattern of misbehavior is bizarre.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that does have to be considered, is that in the grand scheme of things, quite often TWO different people will pick the exact same winning lottery numbers, quite at random.  i.e. there's a 290 million-to-one chance against it happening, but it happens a LOT.  CASE IN POINT:  the january powerball drawing:  3 winners.

Particularly when two students have studied together throughout the semester.  It can almost be considered surprising if there wasn't a lot of correlation on the wrong answers!

Finally: high correlation on wrong answers is much more enlightening about the test design itself.  It often means there's a demonstrated deficiency in the match between the test and the material.

EDIT:  another point I'd make is that, good or bad, professors have FAR LESS power than this OP assumes.  I've personally witnessed at least half a dozen cases recently where professors/APs/Lecturers were themselves accused by students of inappropriately exercising their power over students, and each and every one of those professors was literally sweating bullets as the administration bent over backwards TRYING to find the professor at fault.  Now, granted, these were all in state institutions (various states), where there's a decidedly anti-tenure twist in the administration's long-term vision...but...

Comment: It is also partly a matter of how well the wrong answers are designed. Often, on a multi-choice test, one or more choices are so obviously wrong that they might as well not be there. That increases the probability of hitting the same answer by accident.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.  The question was not "How do I prove  her innocence" but "What should she do re: appealing/not appealing".

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, very true.  I hold a patent in educational testing...this kind of thing is what gives designers lost sleep.  Joe, one of the essential components of filing an appeal/challenge, is "do I have a credible defense?  Do I reasonably and beyond some level of doubt prove at least that the professor's reasoning is flawed, and that the probability of random correlation is much higher than he imagines?"

Answer (score 1):

*Firstly having a multiple choice take home exam as part of the final mark is not a valid method of examining a student and shows a very lazy processor!   (Unless workings are also required to be submitted along with the answer, as without having more information than an answer to a multiple choice question, it is not possible to see if someone has cheated.)*

**I think the issue is partly one of timing….**

The professor is willing to let the “cheating” pass with a lower grade and an additional exam, so solving the problem quickly.

Or the appeal process is used that will take some time and generate work for the professor, it may be reasonable while the appeal is going on for the professor to inform the other academic programs about it  (All he has to say is that “I withdraw my letters of recommendation for reasons I am not permitted to tell you”, and leave the “reading between the lines” to others).   By the time the outcome of the appeal is known, it may be too late to get into the PHd.

Very likely the outcome will be along the lines of “*not proven*”, so the processor will still be able to say he/she **believes (but could not prove 100%)** that the students cheated and the students did not show any remorse.  The student can respond with the result of the appeal, but by that time questions has been put into people’s mind……

**This is way each student should have a personal tutor that they can discuss this sort of issue with “of the record”…..**

(I am assuming that the word “professor” is being used to mean someone that is a little more than a post dock, rather than the UK usage of the word.   As if the professor is a top person in the department the politics may decide the outcome of the appeal.)

Comment: _it is reasonable while the appeal is going on for the professor to inform the other academic programs about it_ — **No, it isn't!**  While the appeal is underway, the entire situation should be absolutely confidential.  If I did what you are suggesting, I would almost certainly lose my job, despite having tenure, and rightly so.  Or perhaps you mean "It is reasonable _to assume that_ the professor _would_ inform..."?

Comment: @JeffE,  It depends on what to processor said in the recommendation and if he still stands by it.   All he has to say is that “I withdraw my letters of recommendation for reasons I am not permitted to tell you”, and leave the “reading between the lines” to others.

Comment: @JeffE I interpreted that statement as meaning it is reasonable to assume that, given the strange things we've already seen of this professor, that they very may well also retract their recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

Going straight to the appeal is the obvious answer, but not always the best one.

As of this moment, begin documenting **everything**. Before your friend says another word to the professor, they should secure any documents pertaining to this event (if they have any). They should also try to acquire what they can through other channels before coming back to the professor. Once done, calmly explain to the prof that they did not cheat and losing marks is simply not an option. Without knowing more about the accusation or being shown the proof, they will have no choice but to appeal the decision unless the accusation is dropped.

Send this communication in the morning. If you receive no response by the end of the working day, begin the appeals process. You do not want a vindictive prof having time to build a case against you (and ideally this should have been done the same day the accusation was dropped).

Answer (score 0):

-Check if the professor has a history of such accusations,

-Ask to see the evaluation or have it checked independently

-Document all communications and ensure that all rules and regulations are followed by both parties if not issue written communications asking them to be followed and if not why?

-As part of appeal raise the concern on future prospect and get written confirmation that appeal will address reprisals in all forms

-Prove the statistical  possibility that such an event could occur and has occurred in the past and that they have not been flagged previously

- Be open to some sort of compromise ( at least give the professor an opportunity to save face)
- Let the professor know your intent is strong and you are not open to bullying and threats but your open to work it out regardless.
- Both of you need to be adamant that its not cheating , if one of you gives then both will pay the price.
- Ask what other possibilities exists just something like this could happen and explore if they are applicable. ( same notes, same books same , lectures etc)
- Regardless of what happens , if you know your right stick to your guns , it will help your self esteem and let you sleep at night.

Answer (score -1):

The professor needs to know that your friend knows how to go for his throat on this (metaphorically) and isn't afraid to do it.  Trying to reason her way out of this is not the right approach because she is trying to argue with a crazy person.

Crazy people cannot be reasoned with, but they will modify their behavior when it becomes clear to them that it will be personally damaging to them if it continues.  That is why your friend needs to figure out what her rights are and how to stand up for them in the way that will be most damaging to the professor.

I suggest that your friend figure out how to make an accusation of professional misconduct and to begin proceedings.  It doesn't need to be an appeal to the professor's accusation, it needs to be an accusation of its own for the way he's behaving.  Certainly, if he withdraws recommendations before the process has concluded, that would be grounds for disciplinary action.  Your friend doesn't need to do anything yet that will be permanently damaging to the professor, but she would do well to start the process and get some other people involved.

Comment: I'm not sure if threatening the professor is the best first attempt at resolving this.

Comment: No, no and no. Once you -- the student -- step out of the official and ethical way, there is no chance you win.

Comment: _Crazy people...will modify their behavior when it becomes clear to them that it will be personally damaging to them if it continues_ --- [citation needed]

Comment: Just to be clear, I am not suggesting that your friend go outside of official channels or do anything illegal.  The threat against the professor should be that he should lose standing within his professional community, lose his job, or get a reputation as a whacko.  I'm not suggesting she press the issue to the full extent that she can coming out of the gate, but she should make it clear in a real way that this is the way things will go so the professor will choose to step off.

Comment: As for the request for a citation, this is actually addressed in In Sheep's Clothing: Understanding and Dealing with Manipulative People by George K. Simon, Ph. D.